# Entity Framework creates an empty migration file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created my initial project in Visual Studio and discovered I had used SQL Server after I created my initial migration.  I then changed all the connection information to use MYSQL and connected successfully.  I created the initial migration again and it created all the ASP security tables.  I added a new model and updated the database, but it created an empty migration (just UP/DOWN methods)

I've tried multiple fixes I found here and other sites.  I backed out the second migration and retried. I tried forcing the migration again (-f).  I dropped the new MYSQL db and deleted the migrations then started over, all with the same result.

Here is my model code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace congresssucks_conversion.Models
{
    public class BlogPost : DBContext
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortPost { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the migration file:

```
namespace congresssucks_conversion.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class blogpost : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It completes successfully and no errors in the Terminal Window.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining two separate things, your model class and your database context.

Your BlogPostm class shouldn't inherit DbContext, it should be just a plain C# class.

Then you make a new class that looks something like this:

```
public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogPostm> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have a class that can represent a single post, and another class that can represent a database with a table of multiple blog posts. The migration generator is looking for those `DbSet<whatever>` properties, so you should see real migrations after this change.

There are a lot more ways you can describe what you want Entity Framework to do with your database, so it would be worth reviewing an Entity Framework tutorial.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the quick response.  I added the new class, built, and re-ran the migration with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete a record of last migration from _MigrationHistory table. Maybe This record had been incorrectly created before added DbSet for the new model object to DbContext class. After this delete, new migration was created with correct Up() and Down() methods.

Comment: I tried that.  No  luck.  I also dropped the db and recreated it now I get connection errors.  I think I'm going to have to start over with a clean project.